# No puedo instalar la librería @vscode/sqlite3

Tags: nodejs, sqlite, vscode, sqlite3, knex

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas estoy intentando instalar la librería @vscode/sqlite3 y no logro avanzar, alguno le ocurrió este error?

Comment: Entiendo que lo que estás intentando es un npm i vscode-sqlite3?

Comment: Intento instalar la libreria @vscode/sqlite3 que supuestamente es la que se necesita para trabajar con Knex

Answer (score 0):

Si es para usar knex, y según la [documentación oficial](https://knexjs.org/), tendrás que lanzar los siguiente comandos:

```
$ npm install knex --save

# Then add one of the following (adding a --save) flag:
...
$ npm install @vscode/sqlite3 --save # required for sqlite
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Estaba mal la variable de entorno de Python, la misma estaba referenciada al disco D y este se encontraba instalado en del C.